# How can I vertically align two inputs and put them together as one?

Tags: html, css, input, bootstrap-4, alignment

I have been trying to create two inputs inside a container where both of them are vertically aligned. Have the "Enter email" on top and the "Password" right below it with no space in between and without having two border from both inputs. This is my code. I am using Bootstrap. I've tried to used vertical align but it did not work (vcenter).

```
<div class=" col-4 offset-md-4 text-center list-group">
          <li style="list-style: none;">
            <input type="email" name="" class="form-control list-group-item" placeholder="Email address">
          </li>
          <li  style="list-style: none">
          <input type="password" name="" class=" form-control list-group-item" placeholder="Password">
          </li>
</div>
```

Again, I need two inputs in one just like the "list groups" in bootstrap but with inputs instead of

. This is the bootstrap code for the list.

```
 <ul class="list-group">
  <li class="list-group-item">Cras justo odio</li>
  <li class="list-group-item">Dapibus ac facilisis in</li>
  <li class="list-group-item">Morbi leo risus</li>
  <li class="list-group-item">Porta ac consectetur ac</li>
  <li class="list-group-item">Vestibulum at eros</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Normally the class `list-group-item` would go on the `<li>` and then the borders would be as you want with bootstrap.css.  Since you have it on the `<input>`  I wanted to utilize as much of the stock bootrap.css as I could with [this solution](https://mdbootstrap.com/snippets/jquery/milkytech/2195015).  Notice I removed your inline style and changed your `<div>` to an unordered list tag `<ul>` for a proper list.  Then you can add the class `list-unstyled` to the `<ul>` rather than an inline style on each list item (`<li>`).  I also gave the list an ID so you could target the input easier to have the `border-top` on the first input.

```css
input.list-group-item {
    border-top-width: 0;
}
#formlist>li:first-child>input {
    border-top-width: 1px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<ul id="formlist" class="list-unstyled col-4 offset-md-4 text-center list-group">
  <li>
    <input type="email" name="" class="form-control list-group-item" placeholder="Email address">
  </li>
  <li>
    <input type="password" name="" class=" form-control list-group-item" placeholder="Password">
  </li>
</ul>
```